# Understanding Spring MVC web application context initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to understand working of Spring MVC framework and was reading [this article](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts).

It says:

> `ContextLoaderListener` creates a root web-application-context for the web-application and puts it in the `ServletContext`.

I was able to find this done at [line 294](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.java#L294) of `ContextLoader`. (Am I seeing at right line of source code / understanding it correct?)

The article further says:

> When `ContextLoaderListener` is used in tandem with `DispatcherServlet`, a root web-application-context is created first as said earlier and a child-context is also created by `DispatcherSerlvet` and is attached to the root application-context.

I am unable to find where (line in [`DispatcherServlet`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java)'s source code or somewhere else) child-context created by `DispatcherServlet` is "attached to the root application context"?

Comment: you are looking at the current master branch, the article was issued in 2014

Comment: whoooaaaa...stuff has changed now!!!!??? Yes possibly...but then what applies now?